# Pytorch using Multi GPU / accuracy is too low(10%)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
for epoch in range(epoch_num):  
    for i,(images, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
        images=images.to(device)
        labels=labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        #Forward Backward Optimize
        outputs = net(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        if i%1000==0:
            print('Number of epochs: %d, Mini Batch order: %d' %(epoch+1,i))
```

This is a train part. I use four GPUs to train. And after I run 5000 epochs (batch size is 128), the accuracy comes out "10%"!! It's too low!
Following is the test part:

```
with torch.no_grad():
num_correct = 0
total_data = 0
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    for images, labels in testloader:
        images=images.to(device)
        labels=labels.to(device)
        output = net(images)
        _, expected = torch.max(output.data, 1)

        total_data += labels.size(0)
        num_correct += (expected == labels).sum().item()
```

I have no idea what is wrong, how can I investigate this?

Comment: is it better than you're using one GPU?

Comment: I'm no pro in PyTorch, but i think there could be some problem using `torch.max`. The docu says `values, indices = torch.max(tensor, 1)` , so your `expected` is the index of the value with the maximum value in `output.data` - are you sure this is correct?
There could be theoretically a lot of other reason for a bad behaviour like bad hyperparameters, overfitting, ...
Also using multiple GPUs shouldn't be the cause of the problem (as far as you're using less than 8 - I think I read something about some problems with 8 or more GPUs)